# Find first value in table in R

Tags: r

I have two columns MPH, Threshold, Car. I’d like to write some code to return the MPH for the column car when the first instance of threshold is 1.

```
MPH         Threshold               Car 
30               0                    A
31               0                    A
32               1                    A
33               1                    A
34               1                    A
35               1                    A
30               0                    B
31               0                    B
32               0                    B
33               0                    B
34               1                    B
35               1                    B
```

Desired Output:

```
Value   Car
32       A
34       B
```

Comment: In base R: `aggregate(MPH ~ Car, data=dat[dat$Threshold == 1,], FUN=head, n=1)`. With `data.table`, you could do `dat[Threshold==1, head(Car, 1), by=Car]`.

Comment: With `dplyr`, it would be something like `dat %>% filter(Threshold == 1) %>% groupby(Car) %>% head(MPH, 1)`, though my tiddly skills are quite lacking, so there is probably a typo or three.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you'll always have at-least one value where `Threshold = 1` for each `Car` we can do

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Car) %>%
  slice(which.max(Threshold == 1)) %>%
  select(-Threshold)

#    MPH  Car  
#  <int> <fct>
#1    32  A    
#2    34  B
```

Of using base R `ave`

```
df[with(df, ave(Threshold == 1, Car, FUN = function(x) 
            seq_along(x) == which.max(x))), ]
```

Comment: Why on earth are you using `ave` in base R, instead of the easier ways?

Comment: @smci I don't find `ave` difficult. I couldn't think of other easier ways, you may write up an answer if you know them.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  filter(Threshold == 1) %>%
  subset(!duplicated(Car))


library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df)
dt[Threshold == 1, ][!duplicated(Car),]
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
i1 <- setDT(df)[, .I[which(Threshold == 1)[1]], Car]$V1
df[i1, .(Value = MPH, Car)]
#    Value Car
#1:    32   A
#2:    34   B
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(MPH = c(30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 30L, 31L, 
32L, 33L, 34L, 35L), Threshold = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L), Car = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```